# opening a file without an extension python

Tags: python

I would like to open a file called "summary" and read information out of it to write into an output file, however I cannot open "summary"

I have tried to verify that the path exists - which works:

```
import os.path
print os.path.exists('/Users/alli/Documents/Summer2016/sfit4_trial/summary')
```

This prints out true. However when I try to do

```
import os
import glob
path = '/Users/alli/Documents/Summer2016/sfit4_trial/summary'
for infile in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*')):
    file = open(infile, 'r').read()
    print file
```

Nothing happens. I have looked through similar questions on SO and tried them all but not having any luck. All suggestions welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Is there some reason summary can't have an extension? What is inside the file?

Comment: You aren't writing anything to the file, nor are you opening the file with writing permission.

Comment: "Nothing happens" because the path you supply to `os.path.join` has `summary` as a directory, not a file.  So it will construct: `/Users/alli/Documents/Summer2016/sfit4_trial/summary/*`.

Comment: Is there any reason to bother with the `glob` here?

Comment: another program produces the summary file and I don't want to change the extension because it may interfere with the other program which is essential to data processing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried?

```
...
path = '/Users/alli/Documents/Summer2016/sfit4_trial'
for infile in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, 'summary*')):
    ...
```